# Show the output following the 3 rules(odd, even, sort)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I tried to write follow this specifications:

1. I have an array read from user
2. Odd numbers is necessary to be at beginning
3. Even numbers is necessary to be at the end of array
4. Sort ascending the odd and even number

This is my code:

**UPDATE the code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int j;

int main(void){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n], aux[n], count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            aux[i] = arr[i];
            count = i;
        }
        else
        {
            aux[n - j - 1] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }   

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if( aux[i] > aux[i+1])
        {
            aux[i]   = aux[i] + aux[i+1];
            aux[i+1] = aux[i] - aux[i+1];
            aux[i]   = aux[i] - aux[i+1];

        }
    }

    for(int i = count; i < n; i++){
        if( aux[i] > aux[i+1])
        {
            aux[i]   = aux[i] + aux[i+1];
            aux[i+1] = aux[i] - aux[i+1];
            aux[i]   = aux[i] - aux[i+1];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ", aux[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But, the output is wrong. For example if I entered the dimension of array `4`, and elements of array is `4 3 2 1` the output is: `3 2 1 4196848`, but I want to be `1 3 2 4`. Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: `i < count` in your loop, then you're taking the `i+1` value, which is probably 0 (undefined). undefined behaviour...

Comment: `aux[i] = arr[i];` and `aux[n - i - 1] = arr[i];` --> `aux[other_i?] = arr[i];`

Comment: You sort twice. Why not write a function for this? And your sorting traverses the array only once. This will not work for most arrays.

Comment: @Laurentiu  Don't bother. The whole program is wrong.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this(for current code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h> //unused this

/* It does not have to be a global variables.
int n;
int j;
*/
int main(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n], aux[n], count_odd = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0, even_i = n -1; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            //aux[i] = arr[i]; this is bad. E.g arr:[1,2,3,4] ==> aux:[1,?,3,?] but You want aux:[1,3,?,?]
            //count = i; this is bad. Since count should be number of odd elements, it is not just index of arr.
            aux[count_odd++] = arr[i];
        } else {
            aux[even_i--] = arr[i];
        }
    }   

    //(bubble) sort
    //The position of one element is determined for each loop
    //So in the case of a method of exchanging adjacent elements, it is necessary to double loop.
    //When N elements, the outer loop can be N - 1 times.
    //Since the position of two elements is decided in the last loop.
    //Since one element is determined for each loop,
    //the inner loop can reduce the number of times per outer loop one time.
    for(int j = 0, no = count_odd; j < no - 1; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < no - j - 1; i++){//-1 is a necessary constraint because aux[i+1] does not fall outside the array boundary.
            if( aux[i] > aux[i+1]){
/* Because the result of A + B may overflow, such a method should not be used.
            aux[i]   = aux[i] + aux[i+1];
            aux[i+1] = aux[i] - aux[i+1];
            aux[i]   = aux[i] - aux[i+1];
*/
                int temp = aux[i];
                aux[i]   = aux[i+1];
                aux[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //Since it performs the same processing, it is better to summarize it as a function.
    for(int j = 0, ne = n - count_odd; j < ne - 1; j++){
        for(int i = count_odd; i < n - j - 1; i++){
            if( aux[i] > aux[i+1]){
                int temp = aux[i];
                aux[i]   = aux[i+1];
                aux[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ", aux[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem, but it's good solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behaviour:

```
int main(){
    int n, arr[n], aux[n] = {}, count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

What to you expect to be used as size for those arrays?
`n` is not initialized until you read it with `scanf`.

Besides that you should provide a valid prototype for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initalize your arrays dynamically use *malloc* and pointers instead.

```
int main(){
  int n, count = 0;
  int *arr, *aux;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  arr = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  aux = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole program is wrong starting with the declaration of `main` that in C shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

using objects with indeterminate values as in the declarations of arrays

```
int n, arr[n], aux[n] = {}, count = 0;
   ^^^    ^^^     ^^^
```

(moreover Variable Length Arrays may not be initialized), and ending with three loops commented that they sort something while actually they sort nothing and moreover try to access memory beyond the arrays.

The task can be easy done using standard C function `qsort`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int odd_even(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    int a = *(const int *)lhs;
    int b = *(const int *)rhs;

    return (a % 2 == b % 2) ? (b < a) - (a < b) : b % 2 - a % 2;
}


int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1;   //  1 is minimum acceptable array size

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int a[n];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i] );

    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), odd_even);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

if the input looks like

```
4
4 3 2 1
```

then the array output will be

```
1 3 2 4
```